# Using TransformerFactory from Home Edition to Enterprise Edition

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I am using a formatting engine in which previously I used the saxon9he.jar in which the configuration I got using "

```
private static TransformerFactory theTransformerFactory = 
                        TransformerFactory.newInstance();

((TransformerFactoryImpl) theTransformerFactory).getConfiguration();
```

Now I want to use `EnterpriseEdition` saxon9ee.jar and I want to use `EnterpriseTransformerFactory` to get the configuration. Can I use this? or what are the changes I need to do for the `EnterpriseEdition` switch from Homedition in the engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon-EE's `EnterpriseTransformerFactory` and `EnterpriseConfiguration` are subclasses of Saxon-HE's `TransformerFactoryImpl` and `Configuration`, so you should be able to use them in exactly the same way with no changes to your application. Of course, to get any benefit you will need to either (a) install a license file, and/or (b) make changes to your code to take advantage of new features.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  

In the HomeEdition, if I use `config.setConfigurationProperty(FeatureKeys.ALLOW_OLD_JAVA_URI_FORMAT, true)` it's not accepting.
It seems it can be set only in EnterpriseEdition. In that even if I set the value as false, its setting only true. Am I doing anything wrong?

I referred the following url.
[link]http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.4/configuration/config-features.html

Comment: This property only affects the way extension functions behave, so it is not relevant to Saxon-HE, and therefore not recognized. The default value is false. If you think setting it to false doesn't work, please submit this as a separate problem with full evidence (preferably on http://saxonica.plan.io/ rather than here).

Comment: Hi Michael Kay, Previously I said like even if I set the value as false, its setting only true. Actually, if I set false it returns true while I get using getConfigurationProperty and if I set true it returns false.